# AWS Elastic Transcoder Status RSS Feed

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-elastictranscoder

It seems that the STATUS RSS feed for Elastic Transcoder service is no longer available and it is deprecated now:-
https://status.aws.amazon.com/rss/elastictranscoder-us-east-1.rss

Can someone confirm if there is an alternate Status RSS feed for the Elastic Transcoder service on status.aws.com that can be used instead of the above feed?

Appreciate your help.